# lombok & jackson do not work together with openjdk12

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, java-12

Reproducible [here](https://github.com/Sergey80/repro):

I used to have java 8.x all was working ok. both open jdk and Oracle.

Once JDK & and Oracle JDK is upgraded, I got exceptions from the `jackson`.

```
    Error:(10, 1) java: constructor ClientResponseData in class my.response.ClientResponseData cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

My ClientResponseData defined as follow:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "ClientResponseData")
@Builder
@Getter
public class ClientResponseData {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "responseCode")
    private String responseCode;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "number")
    private String number;

}
```

The dependency that worked for me before java update:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.18</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in pom.xml, I still use: `<java.version>1.8</java.version>`

After java uprade I had to update the Lombok at least to latest: 1.18.8

Then I start having issues.

```
  Error:(10, 1) java: constructor ClientResponseData in class my.response.ClientResponseData cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

It fails on:

```
 return new com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper().readValue(xmlString, cls);
```

Any clue how to make it work?

I tried:

- to add @NoArgsConstructor - nope
- update jackson to latest - nope

Comment: add the error you are getting with `@NoArgsConstructor` and the xml you are trying to deserialize

Comment: Well the error points to missing constructor `no arguments`. +1 on @DanielM

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I tried to add no-arg constructor. same thing.

Comment: Added reproducer on git hub: https://github.com/Sergey80/repro

Comment: @DanielM https://github.com/Sergey80/repro/blob/master/noArgsConstructor.png

Answer (score 0):

I found that combination of @AllArgsConstructor **and** public ClientResponseData() {} make a trick and it starts working.

(I did not need to this with java 8, but for java11, 12 this only way I could make it work)

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "ClientResponseData")
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ClientResponseData {

    public ClientResponseData() {}

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "responseCode")
    private String responseCode;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "number")
    private String number;

}
```

If there is a better solution, please let me know!

Also:

@AllArgsConstructor +
@NoArgsConstructor

makes a trick too.